# merging two html strings into one, using python

Tags: python, html

im trying to understand if there's a relatively simple way, to take an HTML string, and "insert" it inside a different HTML string. I Tried converting the HTML into a simple DIV, and put it in the first HTML, but that didn't work and caused weird failures.

Some more info: I'm creating a report using bokeh, and have some figures. My code is creating some figures and appending them to a list, which eventually is parsed into an HTML and saved on my PC. What i want to do, is read a different HTML string, and append it entirely in my report.

Comment: Well, append or insert?

Comment: That's all a bit vague. Please post your malfunctioning code, tell us what goes wrong, the input you gave it, the expected output,...

Comment: @Jan Christoph Terasa, i guess what im trying to do is, take a raw HTML string, and just put it inside another HTML body, without changing the parent HTML head. but i don't mean referring, i don't have an HTML link, its a raw string representing an HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with BeautifulSoup. See this example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body><p>my paragraph</p></body></html>")
body = soup.find("body")

new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href="http://www.example.com")
body.append(new_tag)

another_new_tag = soup.new_tag("p")
another_new_tag.insert(0, NavigableString("bla bla, and more bla"))
body.append(another_new_tag)

print(soup.prettify())
```

The result is:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   my paragraph
  </p>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">
  </a>
  <p>
   bla bla, and more bla
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tamirg - thoughts?

Comment: @Roy2102 i need something like this, but without referring another HTML, i don't have a link, i have a raw HTML inside a string variable.

Comment: @tamirg - do you mean the 'child' HTML is just a string? If so - that's fine. You can add any kind of HTML as a child. I used an 'a' element in my example - but it could be anything.

Comment: @tamirg - is this a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

So what i was looking for, and what solves my problem, is just using iframe with srcdoc attribute.

```
iframe = '<iframe srcdoc="%s"></iframe>' % raw_html
```

and then i can push this iframe into the original HTML wherever i want